# Error Installing a Canon MX410 driver on Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, ubuntu-drivers

I cant get connected to my Canon MX410 printer. I downloaded a driver but not sure if its the correct one - cnijfilter-mx410series-3.50-1-deb

This is the error:

```
==================================================

Canon Inkjet Printer Driver Ver.3.50-1 for Linux
Copyright CANON INC. 2001-2011
All Rights Reserved.

==================================================
Command executed = sudo dpkg -iG ./packages/cnijfilter-common_3.50-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package cnijfilter-common.
(Reading database ... 213724 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cnijfilter-common_3.50-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cnijfilter-common (3.50-1) ...
Setting up cnijfilter-common (3.50-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Command executed = sudo dpkg -iG ./packages/cnijfilter-mx410series_3.50-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package cnijfilter-mx410series.
(Reading database ... 213740 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cnijfilter-mx410series_3.50-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cnijfilter-mx410series (3.50-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cnijfilter-mx410series:
 cnijfilter-mx410series depends on libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.8.0); however:
  Package libgtk2.0-0 is not installed.
 cnijfilter-mx410series depends on libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.12.3); however:
  Package libpango1.0-0 is not installed.
 cnijfilter-mx410series depends on libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.8rel); however:
  Package libpng12-0 is not installed.
 cnijfilter-mx410series depends on libtiff4; however:
  Package libtiff4 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package cnijfilter-mx410series (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cnijfilter-mx410series
Command executed = sudo dpkg -P cnijfilter-mx410series
(Reading database ... 213944 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing cnijfilter-mx410series (3.50-1) ...
Purging configuration files for cnijfilter-mx410series (3.50-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Command executed = sudo dpkg -P cnijfilter-common
(Reading database ... 213740 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing cnijfilter-common (3.50-1) ...
Purging configuration files for cnijfilter-common (3.50-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
```

Comment: It is a over 10 year old driver. Good chance what it wants no longer exists in the OS.